# How to remove "Categories:" part after the post title?

Tags: categories

Im quite new to wordpress and trying to figure out the problem shown on the picture. Cant find the place to hide it.Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It is in the template somewhere, maybe in a separate part. If you are using linux try `grep 'Categories' * -rn` inside the theme folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Wordpress theme you're using. If you can find out what html class the category/post meta is under using Inspect Element, it will be easy to hide it via CSS. Otherwise you will need to find where the 'Post Meta Data' is being added in PHP inside your theme and remove it.

For now you can try and paste the following code inside your style.css file and see if it works, but it's just guessing at this stage:

```
footer.entry-footer, .entry-meta {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that took me a step closer to solution.